# Update table rows using jQuery HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a table. In that, I want to do add, delete and update operation dynamically. Here in my code,I am adding and deleting rows to table dynamically, now I want to edit table rows by jQuery. What will be the code for update function?

Here, I have added my javascript code.

```
function Add() {
        AddRow($("#txtName").val(), $("#txtEmail").val(), $("#txtCity").val());
        $("#txtName").val("");
        $("#txtEmail").val("");
        $("#txtCity").val("");
    };

    function AddRow(name, email, city) {

        var tBody = $("#tblCustomers > TBODY")[0]; 

        row = tBody.insertRow(-1); 
        console.log(row);

        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(name); 

        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(email);

        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(city);

        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        var btnRemove = $("<input />");
        btnRemove.attr("type", "button");
        btnRemove.attr("onclick", "Remove(this);");
        btnRemove.val("Remove");            
        var btnEdit = $("<input />");
        btnEdit.attr("type", "button");
        btnEdit.attr("onclick", "Edit(this);");
        btnEdit.val("Edit");
        cell.append(btnRemove," ",btnEdit);
    };

    function Remove(button) {

        var row = $(button).closest("TR");            
        var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
        console.log(row,name,row[0].rowIndex);
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete: " + name)) {

            var table = $("#tblCustomers")[0];

            table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
        }
    };

    function Edit(button) {

         var row = $(button).closest("TR");
         console.log(row);         
         var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
         var email = $("TD", row).eq(1).html();
         var city = $("TD", row).eq(2).html();

         if (confirm("Do you want to update: " + name)) {

            var table = $("#tblCustomers")[0];
            console.log(row,name,row[0].rowIndex);
            $("#txtName").val(name);
            $("#txtEmail").val(email);
            $("#txtCity").val(city);

            $('#button1').html("<input type='button' value='Update' onclick=update(this);> <input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick=Cancel();>");      
            return false;
        }
    };
    function update(button)
    {   
        // updation code here..


    };

    function Cancel()
    {               
        $('#button1').html("<input type='button' value='Add' onclick=Add();>");
        $("#txtName").val("");
        $("#txtEmail").val("");
        $("#txtCity").val("");
        return false;
    }
```

HTML code:

```
 <form>
    Name: <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder=" Name"><br><br>
    Email: <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder=" Email"><br><br>
    City: <input type="text" id="txtCity" placeholder=" City"><br><br>        
   <div id="button1"> <input type="button" id="add" onclick="Add()" value="Add Row"> </div>
</form>
<table id="tblCustomers">
    <thead>
        <tr>                
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>   
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Action</th>             
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>            
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
 table{
        width: 60%;
        margin: 20px 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    }
    table th, table td{
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function update(button, trindex) {
  var row = $("table tbody tr:eq(" + trindex + ")");
  row.find("td:eq(0)").html($("#txtName").val())
  row.find("td:eq(1)").html($("#txtEmail").val())
  row.find("td:eq(2)").html($("#txtCity").val())
  $('#button1').html("<input type='button' value='Add' onclick=Add();>");
};
```

Check the demo below for full code.

```js
function Add() {
  AddRow($("#txtName").val(), $("#txtEmail").val(), $("#txtCity").val());
  $("#txtName").val("");
  $("#txtEmail").val("");
  $("#txtCity").val("");
};

function AddRow(name, email, city) {

  var tBody = $("#tblCustomers > TBODY")[0];

  row = tBody.insertRow(-1);


  var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
  cell.html(name);

  cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
  cell.html(email);

  cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
  cell.html(city);

  cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
  var btnRemove = $("<input />");
  btnRemove.attr("type", "button");
  btnRemove.attr("onclick", "Remove(this);");
  btnRemove.val("Remove");
  var btnEdit = $("<input />");
  btnEdit.attr("type", "button");
  btnEdit.attr("onclick", "Edit(this);");
  btnEdit.val("Edit");
  cell.append(btnRemove, " ", btnEdit);
};

function Remove(button) {

  var row = $(button).closest("TR");
  var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
  console.log(row, name, row[0].rowIndex);
  if (confirm("Do you want to delete: " + name)) {

    var table = $("#tblCustomers")[0];

    table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
  }
};

function Edit(button) {

  var row = $(button).closest("TR");
  var index = row.index();
  var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
  var email = $("TD", row).eq(1).html();
  var city = $("TD", row).eq(2).html();

  if (confirm("Do you want to update: " + name)) {

    var table = $("#tblCustomers")[0];
    $("#txtName").val(name);
    $("#txtEmail").val(email);
    $("#txtCity").val(city);

    $('#button1').html("<input type='button' value='Update' onclick='update(this," + index + ");'> <input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick=Cancel();>");
    return false;
  }
};

function update(button, trindex) {
  var row = $("table tbody tr:eq(" + trindex + ")");
  row.find("td:eq(0)").html($("#txtName").val())
  row.find("td:eq(1)").html($("#txtEmail").val())
  row.find("td:eq(2)").html($("#txtCity").val())
  $('#button1').html("<input type='button' value='Add' onclick=Add();>");
};

function Cancel() {
  $('#button1').html("<input type='button' value='Add' onclick=Add();>");
  $("#txtName").val("");
  $("#txtEmail").val("");
  $("#txtCity").val("");
  return false;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Name: <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder=" Name"><br><br> Email: <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder=" Email"><br><br> City: <input type="text" id="txtCity" placeholder=" City"><br><br>
  <div id="button1"> <input type="button" id="add" onclick="Add()" value="Add Row"> </div>
</form>
<table id="tblCustomers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. It's working!! You saved my valuable time.